# Differentiability of linear least squares

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, multivariable-calculus

Show that least-squares $\|y-X\beta\|^2$ is twice differentiable and has minimizer. I understand that the second derivative is $X'X$. Also it is a composition of linear function which is differentiable and norm which is also differentiable? How to show rigorously twice differentiablity without referring to other results?

Answer (score 1):

We're missing some information... I will assume that $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X$ is a $n \times p$ real matrix such that $\mathrm{rank}(X)=p$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$. The function you consider is :

$$
f:
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \mathbb{R}^{p} & \longrightarrow &\mathbb{R} \\
    \beta & \longmapsto & \Vert y - X \beta \Vert^{2} \\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

$f$ is twice differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ because it is a composition of two functions which are both twice differentiable. To differentiate $f$, note that :

$$ f(\beta) = \left\langle y-X\beta,y-X\beta \right\rangle $$

where $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ denotes the canonical inner product associated to the euclidean norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$. It follows from the chain rule that :

$$ \mathrm{D}_{\beta} f \cdot h = - 2 h^{\top} X^{\top} (y-X\beta) $$

for $h \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$. We see that $\beta^{\ast} = \big( X^{\top} X \big)^{-1} X^{\top} y$ is a critical point for $f$. Since the euclidean norm is stricly convex, $f$ is strictly convex and $\lim \limits_{\Vert \beta \Vert \to +\infty} f(\beta) = +\infty$ so $f$ has a unique minimizer, which is $\beta^{\ast}$.